# Is it possible to autoformat source code using Clang?

Tags: clang

Is it possible to autoformat translation unit (source code) using Clang C API? I'm able to parse translation unit, but i can't find any according method for my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have made a nice tool for formatting source code already - Have a look at:

`$YOUR_LLVM_DIR/clang/tools/clang-format/ClangFormat.cpp`

Comment: seems to be what i asked for! Though i expected it to use C API. Is there any tool that uses C API?

Comment: @4ntoine none that i know of for this purpose in llvm. unlike LibClang, LibTooling is C++. of course, the easy route would be to either make executing the tool more simple, or create a basic C wrapper for your needs. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTools.html#clang-format

Answer (score 0):

## For Xcode users:

Download and install Package Manager here: http://alcatraz.io

Install ClangFormat by clicking on the icon to the left of it.

In the Edit>Clang Format menu, select `Enable Format on Save`

Now your files will be automatically formatted as you save.